# How to use the /testfor command to detect what a player says in chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I use the `/testfor` command in a command block to test for a specific word that a Minecraft player playing on the server says. For my example, if a player says:

> [Player] - Hi

The command block then says:

> [Command Block] - Hello.

Please help, just trying to create a cool command =) {If This Works Please Tell Me}

Answer (score 2):

You just can't.

As per current, command blocks **cannot** read from the chat line.

Read [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165475/75275) for more information.