# How do I compare a message in chat to another pre-made message?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

You might be a bit concerned about this question, well, I'll explain it!
I want a command block to be searching for anyone saying `.clearchat` and if it comes out true it will clear chat. Is it really possible(?), and if it is leave an answer below!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Actually, you can use `/gamerule <randomWord> <number>` in chat, then in a command block `gamerule <randomWord>` to get the number, then `stats` to do something based off of that value. But that doesn't help you for your case, because you still have the problem that no command can clear the chat of a player. The player has to press F3+D himself.

Comment: Well, you could spam the player's chat with empty lines. But again, only with `gamerule <randomWord> <number>`. Is that also acceptable? Then I already have an answer ready (written months ago, just forgot to post).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use the /testfor command to check for certain words in chat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/can-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-check-for-certain-words-in-chat)

Answer (score 0):

Programmes can in theory read the logs of the game to know what has been typed in the chat. However, command blocks cannot. As far as I know, commands can not clear the chat of a player either.

Comment: Well, that shucks, well I got the clearchat covered.

Comment: Look I know this is old but I want to know a program that can do that. If you know then **THATS AWESOME!!!** Thanks.

Comment: There's a log file for every Minecraft session. You can read that with any text editor, console, batch script, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a command block to clear chat however, Building on @aeldrion’s answer, you can clear the chat for yourself by pressing `F3` + `D`. Depending on your keyboard preferences on providing function keys, you may also have to press `FN` as well for it to work. I’m sorry your objective was not possible and I hope this trick will help you to work around it.