# How To Teleport Someone If He Types "Shop" in a Certain Coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know if this is possible in Minecraft, but I will ask. I want if someone says "*Shop*" in certain coordiantes (Example: `985 53 1100` to `1107 53 978`), he will teleport to `1046 54 1128`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test for people's chat messages. I suggest you learn about commands and try stuff out yourself before asking questions here.

Comment: Was the second half of this answer really necessary?

Comment: I already tried it but nothing was worked. Whatever, thank you for answering...

Comment: I believe the second half of this answer was to iterate the point Frank made in his comment.  Frank does it with tact but the fact still remains, a basic internet search will yield Pepjin's answer.  It will also yield  [Can i use the /testfor command to check for certain words in chat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/can-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-check-for-certain-words-in-chat)