# test for something in chat minecraft command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if there was a way to check if something is said in chat with command blocks. Checking if it was said with /say or /me would be great as well. PC and PE would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: No, there is currently no way of detecting chat events. I would love to see this implemented tho.

Comment: Please limit your question to only one of these two (completely separate) games.

Comment: Fabian Röling same game, two flavors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use the /testfor command to check for certain words in chat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/can-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-check-for-certain-words-in-chat)